# Not able to install the Sikulix setup 1.1.3 jar in Linux

Tags: sikuli-x

Url to download the Sikulix setup 1.1.3 jar : https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download
Command used to install Sikulix setup 1.1.3 jar -->java -jar Sikulix setup 1.1.3 jar
While installing sikulix setup 1.1.3 jar, i am getting the error as 'Something serious happened! Sikuli Not Usable'... Check the error log

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is new version 2.x of Sikuli that works on latest Linux OS. Old 1.1.3 is not supported anymore

However the answer your question: you need manually to install Java opencv library in older Sikuli versions. Note this will work on Ubuntu 16 and 14.